# Using javascript in sharepoint 2013

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I have created a list in sharepoint 2013 and from that list a form has been created.I have a field called formID and when the form is generated, a textbox was automatically created for that field. I need to used JavaScript in order to modify that textbox.

Below is the code generated for the textbox

```
<SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
```

Here is the HTML. This HTML has also been created by sharepoint

```
    <WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart runat="server" EnableOriginalValue="False" DisplayName="commonPage" ViewFlag="8" ViewContentTypeId="" Default="FALSE" ListUrl="" ListDisplayName="" ListName="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}" ListId="fa03b5da-da12-404a-a3d7-531af64c0f93" PageType="PAGE_NEWFORM" PageSize="-1" UseSQLDataSourcePaging="True" DataSourceID="" ShowWithSampleData="False" AsyncRefresh="False" ManualRefresh="False" AutoRefresh="False" AutoRefreshInterval="60" NoDefaultStyle="TRUE" InitialAsyncDataFetch="False" Title="commonPage" FrameType="None" SuppressWebPartChrome="False" Description="" IsIncluded="True" PartOrder="2" FrameState="Normal" AllowRemove="True" AllowZoneChange="True" AllowMinimize="True" AllowConnect="True" AllowEdit="True" AllowHide="True" IsVisible="True" DetailLink="" HelpLink="" HelpMode="Modeless" Dir="Default" PartImageSmall="" MissingAssembly="Cannot import this Web Part." PartImageLarge="" IsIncludedFilter="" ExportControlledProperties="True" ConnectionID="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000" ID="g_dad58f58_2e43_4881_882e_ab840e0d9b4f" ChromeType="None" ExportMode="All" __MarkupType="vsattributemarkup" __WebPartId="{DAD58F58-2E43-4881-882E-AB840E0D9B4F}" __AllowXSLTEditing="true" WebPart="true" Height="" Width=""><DataSources>
<SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="ListItem" SelectCommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;ContentType&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Item&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True"><SelectParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://tcfddemo.sharepoint.com/sites/Adelphi" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </SelectParameters><UpdateParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://tcfddemo.sharepoint.com/sites/Adelphi" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </UpdateParameters><InsertParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://tcfddemo.sharepoint.com/sites/Adelphi" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </InsertParameters><DeleteParameters><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListItemId" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="0" Name="ListItemId"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="weburl" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="https://tcfddemo.sharepoint.com/sites/Adelphi" Name="weburl"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter><WebPartPages:DataFormParameter ParameterKey="ListID" PropertyName="ParameterValues" DefaultValue="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}" Name="ListID"></WebPartPages:DataFormParameter>
            </DeleteParameters>
</SharePoint:SPDataSource>
</DataSources>
<Xsl>



<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl msxsl ddwrt" xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" xmlns:ddwrt2="urn:frontpage:internal">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="no"/>
    <xsl:decimal-format NaN=""/>
    <xsl:param name="dvt_apos">&apos;</xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="ManualRefresh"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:variable name="dvt_1_automode">0</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:template match="/" xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:dsp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/dsp" xmlns:asp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ASPNET/20" xmlns:__designer="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/designer" xmlns:SharePoint="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="($ManualRefresh = 'True')">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td valign="top">
                            <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td width="1%" class="ms-vb" valign="top">
                            <img src="/_layouts/15/images/staticrefresh.gif" id="ManualRefresh" border="0" onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__cancel')}" alt="Click here to refresh the dataview."/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dvt_1">
        <xsl:variable name="dvt_StyleName">ListForm</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="Rows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Rows/Row"/>
        <div>
            <span id="part1">
                <table border="0" width="100%">
                    <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.body">
                        <xsl:with-param name="Rows" select="$Rows"/>
                    </xsl:call-template>
                </table>
            </span>
            <SharePoint:AttachmentUpload runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
            <SharePoint:ItemHiddenVersion runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.body">
        <xsl:param name="Rows"/>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="gobackbutton1"/>
                        </td>
                        <td><input type="text" id="userType"/></td> <!-- look here -->
                        <td><input type="button" value="click here to change view" id="userTypeButton" onclick="function1()"/></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <SharePoint:FormToolBar runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
                <SharePoint:ItemValidationFailedMessage runat="server" ControlMode="New"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:call-template name="dvt_1.rowedit"/>
        <tr>
            <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="99%" class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap"><IMG SRC="/_layouts/15/images/blank.gif" width="1" height="18"/></td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap">
                            <SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="savebutton2"/>
                        </td>
                        <td class="ms-separator">&#160;</td>
                        <td class="ms-toolbar" nowrap="nowrap" align="right">
                            <SharePoint:GoBackButton runat="server" ControlMode="New" id="gobackbutton2"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template name="dvt_1.rowedit">
        <xsl:param name="Pos" select="position()"/>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table border="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>formID<span class="ms-formvalidation"> *</span>
                                </nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody" >
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff1{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Title" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff1',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Title')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff1description{$Pos}" FieldName="Title" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>surgeon_name</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff2{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="tsnn" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff2',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@tsnn')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff2description{$Pos}" FieldName="tsnn" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>surgeon_surname</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff3{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="_x0069_xr2" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff3',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@_x0069_xr2')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff3description{$Pos}" FieldName="_x0069_xr2" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>date_created</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff4{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="date_created" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff4',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@date_created')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff4description{$Pos}" FieldName="date_created" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>lab_name</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff5{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="d0h5" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff5',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@d0h5')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff5description{$Pos}" FieldName="d0h5" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>lab_surname</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff6{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="zn0z" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff6',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@zn0z')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff6description{$Pos}" FieldName="zn0z" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td width="190px" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel">
                            <H3 class="ms-standardheader">
                                <nobr>status</nobr>
                            </H3>
                        </td>
                        <td width="400px" valign="top" class="ms-formbody">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="ff7{$Pos}" ControlMode="New" FieldName="status" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i',concat('ff7',$Pos),'Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@status')}"/>
                            <SharePoint:FieldDescription runat="server" id="ff7description{$Pos}" FieldName="status" ControlMode="New"/>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="idAttachmentsRow">
                        <td nowrap="true" valign="top" class="ms-formlabel" width="20%">
                            <SharePoint:FieldLabel ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" runat="server"/>
                        </td>
                        <td valign="top" class="ms-formbody" width="80%">
                            <SharePoint:FormField runat="server" id="AttachmentsField" ControlMode="New" FieldName="Attachments" __designer:bind="{ddwrt:DataBind('i','AttachmentsField','Value','ValueChanged','ID',ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID)),'@Attachments')}"/>
                            <script>
          var elm = document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsTable&quot;);
          if (elm == null || elm.rows.length == 0)
          document.getElementById(&quot;idAttachmentsRow&quot;).style.display=&apos;none&apos;;
        </script>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:if test="$dvt_1_automode = '1'" ddwrt:cf_ignore="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="99" class="ms-vb">
                                <span ddwrt:amkeyfield="ID" ddwrt:amkeyvalue="ddwrt:EscapeDelims(string(@ID))" ddwrt:ammode="view"></span>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </xsl:if>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>   </Xsl>
<DataFields>
</DataFields>
<ParameterBindings>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListItemId" Location="QueryString(ID)" DefaultValue="0"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="weburl" Location="None" DefaultValue="https://tcfddemo.sharepoint.com/sites/Adelphi"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ListID" Location="None" DefaultValue="{FA03B5DA-DA12-404A-A3D7-531AF64C0F93}"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="dvt_apos" Location="Postback;Connection"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="ManualRefresh" Location="WPProperty[ManualRefresh]"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="UserID" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentUserName"/>
         <ParameterBinding Name="Today" Location="CAMLVariable" DefaultValue="CurrentDate"/>
     </ParameterBindings>
</WebPartPages:DataFormWebPart>
```

and here is the javascript I wrote

```
<script>
    function function1(){
    var type=document.getElementById(&quot;userType&quot;).value;
        //window.alert(type);
        if(type==&quot;lab&quot;){
            window.alert(&quot;you are lab&quot;);
            document.getElementById(&quot;ff1{$Pos}&quot;).disabled=true;
        }
        else if (type==&quot;surgeon&quot;){
            window.alert(&quot;you are surgeon&quot;);
        }

    }
</script>
```

My question is how do I access this textbox using "document.getElementByID" and pure javascript. I have tried to use the default ID, but it does not work.

Comment: That would be a lot easier to answer if you would show the HTML the client sees.

Comment: Yes, check the source that is generated and use the ID from the html source. It will probably be something like 'ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_[yourID]'

Comment: I have added the generated HTML and the javascript code I wrote. @Verthosa, I tried this but it does not work. Please have a look at the javascript part in my question

Comment: 2 questions, 1) where do you call you function? 2) is it StackOverflow that adds those &quot; things or is this written by you? Otherwise i would suggest to just type ' or " instead of &quot;. Also for debugging reasons, just add a script editor webpart on your page and write alert(document.getElementById('userType')); in script tags just to check. This should work!

Comment: @Verthosa, the function is called when clicking the button having id="userTypeButton". &quot is added automatically by sharepoint designer when in save. alert(document.getElementById('userType')) works but it does not work when I try using that on SharePoint:FormField having id="ff1{$Pos}"

Comment: Hey, Mervyn: just a few things: 1) try writing onclick="javascript: function1();" instead of just the function name and copy/paste the console error of your browser's dev tools 2) Where and how do you reference the javascript in your page? Because i don't see it in the HTML output 3) if you are sure everything is added, try disabling the minimal download feature on your site. This sometimes prevent the javascript from being loaded (something to do with async calls and all)

Comment: @Verthosa I've got the ID of the textbox and tried your first comment. It works. Thank you

Comment: ok, glad i could help

Comment: Would you mind approving the answer below? tnx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To wrap it up: you can get the HTML element through javascript using the generated ID by SharePoint. Just navigate to the page and look at the source. Get the ID from there and use this in your document.getElementById(xxx).

So using 'ff1{$Pos}' won't work as the element's ID is generated/replaced on page load.

The id's will mostle start with ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_[yourid]